# Removing a class then adding it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have a bunch of divs, and the goal is to give the most recently clicked div the active class. Only one div should have that class at a time. I tell it to remove that class from everything, then add it to the clicked element. It doesn't seem to add it back, though.

```
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $("div.rep").one('click', function(){
                $(this).append("Lorem Ipsum");
                $('.active').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass("selected");
            }
        );
    })
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: You're removing and adding the `selected` class, not the `active` class.

Comment: That would do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).addClass("selected");
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

Comment: Barmar got in ahead of me.  Thank him/her.